# Force JSON.stringify to use decimal notation

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

When I send data from the client to the server, the framework I'm using (angularjs) uses `JSON.stringify()` to convert the data to JSON. (It probably uses `angular.toJson()`, but that uses `JSON.stringify()` to do the work.) I'm guessing the stringify function calls `toString()` underneath...

The problem is that very small and very large values are then written in scientific notation. This is a problem for me because it's difficult for the server to determine what to do with the value, causing issues saving data. I'd like my objects to be stringified to decimal-representation, e.g. `.0000004` instead of `4e-7`.

Is this possible? Is it possible to do this globally so that I don't have to modify every POST to the database?

Comment: "difficult for the server to determine what to do with the value" ... ?? `4e-7` is a perfectly good number, and it specifically means the same thing as `0.0000004`. What's your server-side JSON tool?

Comment: I just tested under chrome, JSON.stringify doesn't call toString underneath. `JSON.stringify({toString: function(){return "foo";}});` returns`"{}"`

Comment: c# - JavaScriptSerializer is turning the values into objects. I then throw it in a DataTable, and I have to guess at the datatype.

Comment: Can't you use `TryParse` to see if you can convert it? Is this free-form JSON or does it have a well-defined form? Perhaps it would be better to deserialize it to a concrete class then.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil you are correct. In either case the question stands

Comment: @VivinPaliath I have an array of objects that get converted to a DataTable. It's risky to decide it's a Decimal because the first row (object in array) parses successfully to a decimal. Instead I use something generic like String or Object. The database implicitly converts...but throws an error when it hits `4e-7`. Regarding the concrete class, that would mean creating classes for tens if not hundreds of endpoints. I'd like to keep it generic.

Comment: @AaronGreenwald Well, it depends on the JSON. That's why I asked if the JSON was free-form or if it maps to a particular resource with well-defined semantics and structure. If it does, you are better off creating a DTO for each representation and then serializing from/deserializing to that.

Comment: Scientific notation for numeric values is explicitly valid JSON. If your server-side JSON parser can't correctly translate that representation into some numeric form, then I'd say it's a non-functional JSON parser.

Comment: @Pointy It seems like his parser is able to deal with it properly, but he is having issues when persisting it to the database.

Comment: @AaronGreenwald Another issue I noticed is that you're losing all type information when you convert it to a String/Object. Unless you store type-hints in the database, how will you know what to deserialize to when you return the data? Also if you convert "4e-7" to a String, why is the database having trouble persisting that? Do your columns have specific types? Or are they just text?

Comment: @VivinPaliath it's SQL Server. The datatypes are very strict. The web server is a dumb API, it doesn't do much other than act as a middle tier between a thick database and a thick client. I just want it to transmit what it gets from the client to the database faithfully.

Comment: @Pointy has a point - it is doing that. SQL Server isn't able to handle scientific notation, apparently, so I'm trying to force the values to decimal representation at the source. Pointy would say I should fix the db, not JSON.stringify (which is working correctly).

Comment: @AaronGreenwald It will be very difficult for you to do this properly then. If your columns have strict types, then what you're serializing to should also honor those types. It will be very hard to do that if you are deserializing to just map where the values are either Object or String. Do you have well-defined schema for these tables? Then it would make sense to have a concrete class that represents that.

Comment: @AaronGreenwald that really makes no sense. If the server parses the JSON properly, then you've got (depending on your server language) a floating-point value or some sort of "big decimal" fixed-point value. I know for a fact that SQL server can handle fixed-point values. Scientific notation is a **text** representation for numbers; once it's parsed, you've got a **number** of some type and notation is not relevant.

Comment: Also note that *whatever* numeric type your JSON parser constructs from numeric values in JSON, it's *almost 100% certain* that it's the same type whether the input value is in scientific notation or not. It's *possible* that integers and non-integers are handled differently, but I would be very surprised if `0.0000004` and `4e-7` ended up as anything other then exactly the same numeric value after the JSON were parsed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force float value when using JSON.stringify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399380/force-float-value-when-using-json-stringify)

Answer (score 0):

This may not work in all situations, but I used

```
JSON.stringifyDecimal = function(...args) {
    return JSON.stringify(...args).replace(/[+\-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g,function(match) {
    return (parseFloat(match)).toFixed((!match.toUpperCase().includes("E") ? (match.split('.')[1] || []).length : 20)).replace(/([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+[1-9])?)(\.?0+$)/,'$1');
  });
};
```

Input: `[1.7e-5,5.6666],[1.8e-3,7.211555],[1.9e-2,2.456]`

Output: `[[0.000017,5.6666],[0.0018,7.211555],[0.019,2.456]]`

This implementation allows for up to 20 decimals of precision.