# Force float value when using JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to force a *Number* to be a *Float*, after JSON.stringify(). Unfortunately JSON.stringify() deletes the 1 **.0**.

Example :

```
JSON.stringify(1.0) // "1"
```

Wanted outcome:

```
JSON.stringify(1.0) // "1.0"
```

I'm using an API which wants an object in JSON-Format, but it only understands decimal values. So I wanted to ask if it is possible using JSON.stringify to generate the string with decimal values without using Regex-.replace-magic

Comment: I'm guessing you want it to still output "1" for `JSON.stringify(1)` though? There's no such thing as a "float" in JavaScript, only [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) has an overload which takes a function. Use that to determine what to output.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan no JSON.stringify(1) should also output "1.0". Yes I've seen this overload function. The problem is; when I used `JSON.stringify({Test:1}, function(key, value){ if(key == 'Test') { return value.toFixed(1) } return value; }); // "{"Test":"1.0"}"`. I dont want to have the quotation marks after "Test":**"** 1.0 **"***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well for anyone wondering about the regex magic here it is:
This is taken from stringify-with-floats npm library but modified to support any length of floats.

```js
const beginFloat = "~begin~float~";
const endFloat = "~end~float~";

const stringifyWithFloats =
  (config = {}, decimals = 1) =>
  (inputValue, inputReplacer, space) => {
    const inputReplacerIsFunction = typeof inputReplacer === "function";
    let isFirstIteration = true;
    const jsonReplacer = (key, val) => {
      if (isFirstIteration) {
        isFirstIteration = false;
        return inputReplacerIsFunction ? inputReplacer(key, val) : val;
      }
      let value;
      if (inputReplacerIsFunction) {
        value = inputReplacer(key, val);
      } else if (Array.isArray(inputReplacer)) {
        // remove the property if it is not included in the inputReplacer array
        value = inputReplacer.indexOf(key) !== -1 ? val : undefined;
      } else {
        value = val;
      }
      const forceFloat =
        config[key] === "float" &&
        (value || value === 0) &&
        typeof value === "number" &&
        !value.toString().toLowerCase().includes("e");
      return forceFloat ? `${beginFloat}${value}${endFloat}` : value;
    };
    const json = JSON.stringify(inputValue, jsonReplacer, space);
    const regexReplacer = (match, num) => {
      return num.includes(".") || Number.isNaN(num)
        ? Number.isNaN(num)
          ? num
          : Number(num).toFixed(decimals)
        : `${num}.${"0".repeat(decimals)}`;
    };
    const re = new RegExp(`"${beginFloat}(.+?)${endFloat}"`, "g");
    return json.replace(re, regexReplacer);
  };

const test = {
  test: "test",
  float: 1.2,
  number: 1,
};

const formatted = stringifyWithFloats(
  { float: "float", number: "float" },
  2
)(test, null, 2); // null and 2 is just for pretty print

console.log(formatted);
```

Answer (score 7):

The straight and reasonably short answer to your question is **no**, you cannot customize the serialization of numeric values with JSON.stringify. See [JSON.stringify() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

If you really need decimals for your integers you have to use "regex-magic" as you mention in your question or find a library allowing you to perform such tricks. If you aren't dealing with overly complex or many different kinds of objects you could probably stringify them manually.

As a sidenote, it sounds very, very suspicious with an API that needs to be fed with custom formatted JSON. I would tripple-check if there are any other way of using it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well I'll figure something out. Unfortunately this will affect the cleanness of my code :( Well it is true, I must use double values, I triple checked it. I'm not directly using an API, but something equivalent. I want to create a library which generates "Minecraft Commands", and these commands dont get parsed well by Minecraft. If you want to know more about this issue, pm me, otherwise, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 6):

Use **toFixed** instead of stringify. Example:

```
var num = 1;
var numStr = num.toFixed(1); //result is "1.0"
```

More about **toFixed** - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp.

To be clear We are talking about conversion **number to string** not number to float ( such type not exists in javascript ) like can be understood from question description. `toFixed` will always return String with specified number of decimals.

Comment: I would recommend using MDN for references ([`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)).

Comment: would result to to `JSON.stringify(1.toFixed(1)) // '"1.0"'`. Not what I'm searching for. It must'nt have quotation marks

Comment: @LivioBrunner way You are stringify String again? toFixed gives string so not need to use it inside stringify again.

Comment: @MaciejSikora unfortunately I must use JSON.stringify() :/

Comment: Problem is; I'm using an API which wants an object in JSON-Format, but it only understands decmiaml values. So I wanted to ask if it is possible using JSON.stringify to generate the string with decimal values without using Regex-.replace-magic