# Parse float with decimals to JSON in JavaScript also for 1 as 1.00

Tags: javascript, json, floating-point, node-red

**The situation:**
My sensor measures data, that I process in a NodeRED-function and afterwards parse into a JSON-object. The NodeRED-function allows me to write JavaScript-Code. The JSON-object gets send to a receiving module, written in C++, that works on the JSON with the JSON_spirit library.  I can not change the receiving module.

**The problem:** The receiving app tries to get one value of the JSOn with the function `value.get_float()`. The sensors sometimes measure an exact 1.00. That gets passed to the JSON as `{"value":1}`. The receiving module terminates with the Error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  get_value< real > called on integer Value
```

Obviously, the function `value.get_float()` seems not to be able to change an 1 into a 1.0 and, as mentioned, I can not change the used function. So, I need to find a way to parse `{"value":1.00}` into the JSON.

**What I have tried:**
I tried in my NodeRED function `value.toFixed(2)` but this would return a string `{"value":"1.00"}`. 
So, I tried to parse the string as a float again like this

```
value.toFixed(2);
value = parseFloat(value);
```

But this would lead for a 1.00 again to a JSON like this: `{"value":1}`.
I tried some tricks with rounding as well, but as soon as JavaScript can omit unnecessary decimals, it does. So, I havent found a solution yet.

Any ideas are welcome.

P.S.: This is my first time ever StackOverflow question so please do not be too harsh on me :)

---

**Edit:** I found the following workaround.
I use `value.toFixed(2);` in a first note to get `{"value":"1.00"}`. Later on, I use a regular expression on the string in a change-Node in NodeRED.
RegEx:

```
"Value":\"(\d+\.\d{2})\"
```

Replace with:

```
"Value":$1
```

My real case was a bit more complex than the example, so the regex was a little longer. But [regex101](https://regex101.com/) helped a lot.

Comment: If you have a solution please add it as an answer and mark it as accepted rather than edit the question, this helps others find it easier.

Answer (score 1):

Think this post was already been there:
[Force float value when using JSON.stringify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399380/force-float-value-when-using-json-stringify)

So i think in Javascript there is no difference between 1 and 1.0

Comment: Thanks. 
Your link leads exactly to what I needed to know. Unfortunately I did not find it in the first place myself.

But the answers in the other question state, that it seems to be not possible to achieve what I need :(

Comment: Yea sadly :(   maybe it is using an explicit datatype for json. I think there was something on which you could identify the value als float